# Renaming nodes and values with xslt

Tags: xslt, rename, xslt-1.0

I'm new to xslt, and have a task that I'm not really sure where to go with. I want to rename nodes, but maintain the format all node declarations. In the actual context I'll be applying this to, I'll be doing a series of renames like this, but for the sake of brevity, the sample I've written up only involves renaming one node. I am using XSL 1.0.

**Input:**

```
<variables>
  <var>
    <RENAME> a </RENAME>
  </var>
  <var RENAME='b'/>
  <var>
    <DO_NOT_TOUCH> c </DO_NOT_TOUCH>
  </var>
  <var DO_NOT_TOUCH='d'/>
</variables>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<variables>
  <var>
    <DONE> a </DONE>
  </var>
  <var DONE='b'/>
  <var>
    <DO_NOT_TOUCH> c </DO_NOT_TOUCH>
  </var>
  <var DO_NOT_TOUCH='d'/>
</variables>
```

**My xslt:**

```
<xsl:template match="RENAME">
        <RENAMED>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </RENAMED>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Current Output**

```
<variables>
  <var>
    <RENAMED> a </RENAMED>
  </var>
  <var RENAME="b">
  </var>
  <var>
    <DO_NOT_TOUCH> c </DO_NOT_TOUCH>
  </var>
  <var DO_NOT_TOUCH="d">
  </var>
</variables>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="RENAME">
        <DONE>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </DONE>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@RENAME">
        <xsl:attribute name="DONE">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output against your sample:

```
<variables>
    <var>
        <DONE> a </DONE>
    </var>
    <var DONE="b"></var>
    <var>
        <DO_NOT_TOUCH> c </DO_NOT_TOUCH>
    </var>
    <var DO_NOT_TOUCH="d"></var>
</variables>
```

Comment: Thanks for this wizardry. Helps me a lot in wrapping my head around xslt.

Answer (score 0):

This could work also, but it I believe the other answer is better. Just thought I'd offer my two cents.

```
<xsl:variable name="Foo" select="DONE"/>

<variables>
  <var>
    <xsl:element name="{$Foo}"> a </xsl:element>
  </var>
  <var DONE='b'/>
  <var>
    <DO_NOT_TOUCH> c </DO_NOT_TOUCH>
  </var>
  <var DO_NOT_TOUCH='d'/>
</variables>
```