# XSLT / XML Transformation starter

Tags: xml, xslt

New to XSLT/XML transformations and in need of some basic help if possible.

I have an XML file which is similar to

```
<inputName attribute1="renameUsingThis"> Data </inputName>
```

I require the output to be

```
<renameUsingThis attribute1="renameUsingThis"> Data </renameUsingThis>
```

I've seen some examples on here, but can't tweak to how I need it and don't know enough to reverse engineer at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is pretty close to your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970678/renaming-nodes-and-values-with-xslt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="inputName">
        <xsl:element name="{@attribute1}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You may test transformation here: http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/4DKz0w

Comment: I had not seen XSLTCake. Pretty cool idea. (Wish it would run XSLT 2.0.) If you don't mind my curiosity, what part of K'stan are you in? I lived in Almaty, Turkistan, Qaraghanda.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Great help.

However if this is run over multi lines of XML, so the same line repeated, it throws an error. Is there a way to loop this?

Comment: Try add root element in xml file [demo](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/tyCenb). About root element [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element)

Comment: I'd just come back to say that's what I was missing :-) Thanks for your help