# XSLT Transformation of SOAP message content

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:wordList xmlns:ns2="http://service/">
            <prefix1>b</prefix1>
            <prefix2>a</prefix2>
        </ns2:wordList>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I want to transform this file to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:wordList xmlns:ns2="http://service/">
            <pre1>b</pre1>
            <pre2>a</pre2>
        </ns2:wordList>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

However what I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>



            <pre1 xmlns:ns2="http://ws/">b</pre1>
            <pre2 xmlns:ns2="http://ws/">a</pre2>
```

My transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns2="http://ws/"
                version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns2:wordList">
        <ns2:wordList xmlns:ns2="http://ws/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ns2:wordList>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pre1|prefix1">
        <pre1>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </pre1>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pre2|prefix2">
        <pre2>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </pre2>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Why do I lose almost all information? I would think XSL transformation would just copy all elements that are not specified by a certain template, but instead everything seems to get lost apart from the information contained withing the "pre" templates.

Comment: Your use of XML namespaces is inconsistent and confusing. What's the point of registering the same namespace with two different prefixes (`S` and `SOAP-ENV`)? What is `http://ws/` supposed to be? That's in none of your input documents. Finally, XSLT does not "just copy all elements that are not specified by a certain template". That's the job of the identity template – which you don't have in your XSLT.

Comment: This can also be seen as a duplicate of questions like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970678/renaming-nodes-and-values-with-xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in my comment, you need to use the identity template if you want to produce identical output.

It's not *XSLT* that magically copies your input document - it's this template.

After you have that template in place you can override it for the elements you don't want to blindly copy.

In your case you don't want to copy `<prefix1>` and `<prefix2>`, so we need two extra templates that make changes to those elements.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- custom templates below -->
  <xsl:template match="prefix1">
    <pre1>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </pre1>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="prefix2">
    <pre2>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </pre2>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <S:Body>
    <ns2:wordList xmlns:ns2="http://service/">
        <pre1>b</pre1>
        <pre2>a</pre2>
    </ns2:wordList>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

---

If you can do anything about it, make it so that your input document uses namespace prefixes consistently. For example like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <foo:wordList xmlns:foo="http://service/">
            <prefix1>b</prefix1>
            <prefix2>a</prefix2>
        </foo:wordList>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```